# WebService check if there is data in SQL table

Tags: c#, sql, database, web-services

I'm trying to write a process that checks if there is some data in SQL table.

And then I want to do something depending on if exists or not.

So, I've this code that connects to database and it is selecting the data that I want to get from table.

```
public List<MedidasAdoptar> leerMedidasAdoptar()
    {

        DataSet Datos = new DataSet();
        string connectionString = "Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;Data Source=MyServer;Integrated Security=false;User ID=SQLUser;Password=SQLPass;";
        string selectCommand =
            "SELECT [Número medida], [Cód_ Cliente], [Nombre Cliente], [Cód_ obra], [Nombre obra], Tipo, [Cód_ Medida], [Descripción Medida], [Respuesta Medida] FROM [MyDatabase$My table] " +
            "WHERE [Cód_ Cliente] = "+codigoCliente+" AND [Cód_ obra] = "+codigoObra;
        using (var MyConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        using (var MyDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(selectCommand, MyConnection))
        {
            MyDataAdapter.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            MyDataAdapter.Fill(Datos);
            MyDataAdapter.Dispose();
            MyConnection.Close();
        }
        int i;

        //Right here (If it is possible) I want to determine if there is some data in table 

        try
        {
          //...doing some stuff
        } catch (SqlException e)
        {


            string msg = "";
            System.Console.WriteLine(msg);
            return new List<MedidasAdoptar>();
        }
```

Comment: What is the question? You've just stated that you want to do something, and here's the code you used, but you didn't present any problem or question.

Comment: I'm saying it in title. I want to check if there is some data in table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this should work

```
if (Datos.Tables[0].Rows.Count() > 0)
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked in this way:
if (Datos.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)